# How can you enable Clang Format for .c files in Qt creator?

Tags: c, qt-creator

I would like to use the automatic format on save with Clang format in qt creator for my C projects.

I tested the automatic format on save for my C++ projects and it works fine. I also could apply the formatter manually. However, how can I enable this feature to work automatically?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but ... do you really think it's a good idea after all? I personally would **hate** and IDE that fiddles with the formatting when saving. Automated formatting is nice, I sometimes use it, but explicitly -- as there **are** cases where you want to deviate from what the formatter would do. Just my 2 cents ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen, yes, I do. I strongly believe the pros outweigh the cons. One does not die from cases, where the code is formatted in an ugly way, however might cherish the time saved from many more lines of code formatted in a nice way. Nonetheless, a discussion about code formatting is not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

In the Beautifier settings, add `text/x-c` to "Restrict to MIME types: " to also format C